# Message is not getting sent to the user's cell number in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to send OTP on user's mobile number whenever user Sings-up to the app But I am getting an error like this: {"message": "Request path contains unescaped characters"}

I am using [MSG91](https://docs.msg91.com/p/tf9GTextN/e/B1NUt3C8MY/MSG91) to send OTP

The function to send OTP:

```
exports.sendOtp = (message, phoneNumber) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: `api.msg91.com`,
    port: null,
    path: `/api/v5/otp?template_id=&mobile=${phoneNumber}&authkey=${keys.msg91}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const otpData = http.request(options, function (res) {
    const chunks = [];
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
      const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
    });
  });
  otpData.write('{ Value1: "Param1" }');
  otpData.end();
};
```

The function call in the sign-up route:

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { phoneNumber, password, accountType, email } = req.body;
    let check_user = await Auth.findOne({ phoneNumber });
    if (check_user)
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ error: "Phone number is already registered" });

    const hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(password);
    const otp = otpGenerator(4);

    sendOtp(
      {
        message: `Your OTP is ${otp}`,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      },
      next
    );
    const qrData = { phoneNumber };
    let strData = JSON.stringify(qrData);
    const generateQR = await qrcode.toDataURL(strData);
    let new_user = new Auth({
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      accountType,
      otp,
      qrCode: generateQR,
    });

    const payload = {
      id: new_user._id,
      phoneNumber: `${new_user.phoneNumber}`,
    };
    let token = jwt.sign(payload, keys.secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 31556926 });
    const save = await new_user.save();

    res.send({
      success: true,
      msg: "Details saved",
      data: { user: save, token },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: On a security side note - you seem to be trusting the entered phone number and passing this straight in to the request to your sms provider without any validation.

Comment: Phone validation is in the schema.

Comment: What do you mean, _"in the schema"_?

Comment: Ok I got your point. But currently it is not the issue I will set it later. I am sending my phone number with country code.

Answer (score 0):

All URI strings must be encoded via `encodeURIComponent`

`path: encodeURIComponent(yourpath)`

GET request cannot contain `Content-type` header

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving an error in the console: ```<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>```

Comment: @Talc you also trying to set Content-type header for GET request

Comment: It is from the official documentation. I haven't set it up.